# Creating a new data set with same attributes (mean, skew, kurt, product) as old one in R

Tags: r, permutation, data-manipulation

I have a data set x of daily stock returns like this one:

```
1  -0.0053
2   0.0156
3   0.0158
4   0.0044
5   0.0004
6  -0.0194
7   0.0124
8  -0.0023
9   0.0112
10 -0.0358
11  0.0297
12 -0.0058
13  0.0063
14  0.0012
15 -0.0057
16 -0.0070
17  0.0150
18 -0.0045
19 -0.0100
20  0.0055
```

It looks like this in a chart:

[image]

Now what I would like to do is to create a new data set that has the same mean, kurtosis, skew and cumulative return (prod(1 + r)) as the initial data set.

I wrote the following funcion, with limited success:

```
momentsDiffer <- function(x1,x2){
  diff <- sum(abs(moments(x1)- moments(x2)))
  return(diff)
}


function(x,n){  
    # generate from distribution n times storing if improved
    x<- as.numeric(unlist(x))
    current <-  (rnorm(length(x),mean(x), sd(x)))

    momDiff <- (momentsDiffer(x,current))
    for(i in 1:n){
        temp <- (rnorm(length(x),mean(x), sd(x)))
        temp <- (cbind(c(1:length(x)), temp))
        filler1 <- (cbind(c(1:length(x)), filler))
        z <- (cbind(temp,filler1))
        z["z"] <- z["filler"]
        z[z == 0] <- NA
        z$z <- ifelse(is.na(z$z), z$temp, z$z)
        temp <- z["z"]
    temp <- as.numeric(unlist(temp))
        tempDiff <- momentsDiffer(x,temp)
        if((tempDiff < momDiff) & (isTRUE(all.equal(prod(temp + 1), prod(x + 1), tolerance=.0001)))){
            current <- temp
            momDiff <- tempDiff
        }
    }
    return(current)
}
```

I could also achieve the same by re-ordering the initial data set but I do not know of any reordering functions in R.

My goal is to create graphs that look different but have the same attributes that I named.

I would be glad for any help and please excuse my code, it is quite messy.

Comment: Reordering the data could be achieved by using `sample` with replace set to false and size set to the original size of your data.

Comment: I would note that it would not have the same cumulative return, as requested.

Comment: ^ If the time periods are the same, the cumulative return should be the same regardless of order.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(42)
n = 20
library(dplyr)
my_df <- tibble(
  returns = rnorm(n, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.05),
  return_coef = 1 + returns,
  return_cuml = cumprod(return_coef) - 1
)

my_df_reordered <- tibble(
  returns = sample(my_df$returns, n),
  return_coef = 1 + returns,
  return_cuml = cumprod(return_coef) - 1
)

# Despite occurring in different order, the total return is the same
identical(my_df[20,3], my_df_reordered[20,3])
#[1] TRUE


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bind_rows(my_df, my_df_reordered, .id = "version") %>%
         mutate(period = rep(1:20,2))) +
  geom_line(aes(period, return_cuml, color = version)) +
  geom_col(aes(period, returns, fill = version), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you why "tibble"? I make the columns to lists and life pretty hard.

Comment: `tibble` is a variant of `data.frame` and works nicely with dplyr.  https://tibble.tidyverse.org/  If you have a preferred form for the data, it is useful to mention that in your question.

Comment: I tried to adjust your code: _my_df <- tibble(
  returns = rnorm(n, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.05),
  return_coef = 1 + returns,
  return_cuml = cumprod(return_coef) - 1
)_ and added price = 100*cumprod(return_coef). However, it says that is unable to calculate it due to the column being a list. But I wonder why it was able to calculate the other values?